# Script executing before page load

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've finished off a script that runs on a page that contains a textarea where an email goes.

I'm doing a variety of things on this page, however one of these is to load an iframe, based on a selected number, then once the iframe loads grab the relevant details I need from this page.

I've written the code for this inside a function called frameLoaded and I'm setting this as the onload event, yet the script still runs in to an error where it can't find the .innerHTML of an element.

If I load the iframe and then execute this script it works fine, however if I try to load the iframe and execute the script together then it runs in to this error.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
//Getting text currently in the textarea
var selectedTxt = document.getElementById('txtEmailText').value;

//Converting it to a string - this is just for troubleshooting purposes that I've used two variables
var insertText = selectedTxt.toString();

//Loads in the highlighted purchase number
var purchaseNumber = window.getSelection();
purchaseNumber = purchaseNumber.toString();

//Declares global variables to hold the title and number
var purchaseTitle;
var purchaseNumber;

//Function to execute code to grab title and number once the frame has loaded
function frameLoaded() {
var iframe = document.getElementById('purchaseIframe');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
          purchaseTitle = innerDoc.getElementById('listingTitle');
          purchaseNumber = innerDoc.getElementById('auctionSoldIdDisplay');
         }  


//Checks to see if a purchase number has been selected 
if(purchaseNumber.length > 0){

var purchaseIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
purchaseIframe.src = 'http://www.mysite.co.nz/Admin/Listing/PurchaseDisplay.aspx?asid=' + purchaseNumber + '&submit1=++GO++';
purchaseIframe.setAttribute("height","1000");
purchaseIframe.setAttribute("width","100%");
purchaseIframe.setAttribute("id","purchaseIframe");
purchaseIframe.setAttribute("onload", "frameLoaded();");
void(document.body.appendChild(purchaseIframe)); 
}

//Converting the value in the title to readable text
purchaseTitle = purchaseTitle.innerHTML;

//Placing the values in to the format I need
var purchaseDetails = purchaseTitle + " - " + purchaseNumber;

//Placing the values in to the string to go back in to the email textarea
insertText = insertText.replace("PURCHASEDETAILS", purchaseDetails);

//Pasting the variable in to the textarea
document.getElementById('txtEmailText').value = insertText;
```

Am I doing something wrong here or using the wrong event as it seems to me that maybe it's trying to grab the values before the iframe has fully loaded, hence the error when I'm generating the iframe at the same time.

**Please note that I cannot use JQuery**

Comment: Have you tried `purchaseIframe.setAttribute("onload", "frameLoaded");` instead of `purchaseIframe.setAttribute("onload", "frameLoaded();");`?

Answer (score 0):

window.onload = function() is your answer.

Note in the example below, the first instance of document.getElementById('mydiv') returns null because the page (DOM) was not yet loaded and therefore neither was the div.

The second instance is fired on the windows.onload which means all the page content is present and can therefore be found.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
console.log("Page not ready:" + document.getElementById('mydiv'));
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Page ready:" + document.getElementById('mydiv'));
}
</script>

<div id="mydiv">

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid, but where would I place that in my code?
I have tried putting it next to the function `window.onload = function frameLoaded` and `purchaseIframe.setAttribute("window.onload", "frameLoaded();");` but I'm not too sure what to do with this as I don't have access to edit the code within the iframe page.

Comment: You actually want to run your code inside that onload function.  Alternatively you can do something like 

window.onload = init();
function init() {
   //all your stuff
}

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't have access to the the code in the iframe to add that code. So how do I add this to the script execute on the iframe when it loads?

Comment: purchaseIframe.onload = function() {
   this.document.getElementById('SomeElementInsideTheFrame);
}

Comment: have I not already used that by setting up the function frameLoaded and then setting this as an attribute here: `purchaseIframe.setAttribute("onload", "frameLoaded();");`

Comment: what is contentDocument and contentWindowDocument?   The line should be: var innerDoc = iframe.document;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72724/discussion-between-james-and-ryan-tuosto).